# Cygwin terminal not displaying some encoding characters

Tags: character-encoding, cygwin

Cygwin terminal does not display some characters such as Arabic (with the encoding Windows-1256 and  ISO-8859-6). It shows only punctuation and numbers!

Answer (score 6):

I've ran into this.

Firstly ensure that the language is installed in your operating system.
Then right click on the terminal > options > text, set the encoding, locale and a font that you know works for your language.
This should ensure that the correct characters output in the cygwin terminal.